# Graphical problem with top bar and windows

Tags: graphics, themes, window, top-bar

I have these black spots on the top bar. I don't know what causes this problem and how to fix it. Also when I open programs they have blank spots.

[image]

Comment: What ubuntu are you using and what graphics card do you have? Open a terminal, type `lspci -v` and put the output of that call into your question (not into a comment)